# Is there a faster way to connect bluetooth midi devices?

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth, midi

Currently every time you want to reconnect a bluetooth midi device you have to open audio midi setup, open show network browser, find and double click on the bluetooth icon, then connect the device. Is there any terminal shortcut or app to make this process more quickly accessible?

Comment: And here I come almost 4 years later with the same question and no answer, sorry. And the worst thing is, if the MIDI device loses power and comes back, I have to go back through all those windows just to click on "Connect" again. Why can't it auto-connect back automatically? Mac is good for music but sucks for some things.